# How to detect splitViewController hide?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm creating iPad application which is using splitViewController. When app is portrait I want to detect splitViewController hiding and showing. I can detect splitViewController showing using this delegate method.

```
     -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
{

}
```

but I couldn't find any way to detect splitViewController hiding. Any one can give me answer for that.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mentioned method, assign delegate to pc:

```
pc.delegate = self;
```

and implement UIPopoverControllerDelegate method `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` which will be called when popover is dismissed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when hide splitViewController always not fire this method.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to detect masterController visibility. If yes, try this:

```
BOOL isVisible = NO;
if ([[splitViewController viewControllers] count] > 0) {
    isVisible = [[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0].view.window != nil;
}
```

Comment: No. I want to fire method when MasterViewController is hiding.

Comment: Oh, sorry I mean master off course, the code snippet  is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should just read the documentation.
What you want is the documentation about the [UISplitViewController delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISplitViewControllerDelegate)

And from the documentation we can see that you are simply need to use:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
```

Comment: This method only calling when view rotate. But I want to do this one on portrait.